# Servlet instances across multiple mappings

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

If one Servlet is mapped twice, using two different names (as shown bellow) how many instances of the Servlet will be created by the container?

One instance or two or it is container dependent?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.me.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page1.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.me.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page2.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.FooServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>foo</param-name>
        <param-value>bar</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Since each servlet has its own [configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29), there must be at least one servlet instance per servlet definition.

The [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) says:

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
>   the servlet container must use only **one instance per servlet
>   declaration**. However, for a servlet implementing the
>   `SingleThreadModel` interface, the servlet container may instantiate
>   multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and serialize
>   requests to a particular instance.
>
> In the case where a servlet was deployed as part of an application
>   marked in the deployment descriptor as distributable, a container may
>   have only one instance per servlet declaration per Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM™). However, if the servlet in a distributable application
>   implements the `SingleThreadModel` interface, the container may
>   instantiate multiple instances of that servlet in each JVM of the
>   container.

`SingleThreadModel` should be avoided.

Assuming a non-distributed environment, the posted descriptor fragment will result in two servlet instances.

Answer (score 1):

By default `servlets are not thread safe` unless you implement `javax.servelt.SingleThreadModel` *(which is deprecated)*.

Many containers create a single instance for a servlet. ServletMapping has nothing to do with the number of instances that would be created. `ServletMapping just map to the servlet defined using <servlet> tag`.

If you have multiple `<servlet>` tags for the same servlet class with different names. Yes, it will create multiple instances for that servlet. But now when you have mulitiple mappings.

Comment: Does this behavior (creating separate instances for each Servlet name specified in web.xml) come from Servlet specification? What is the benifit of creating separate instances for separate mappings?

Answer (score 0):

It will most likely depend on the implementation of the servlet container.  With whatever you are intending to do, you should assume that a single instance of your servlet will be accessed by multiple threads at once, no matter your servlet-mapping configurations.